# jQuery working in jsFfiddle but not in my PC

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/xhYcD/218/) works fine in jsFiddle but and exports the table into an Excel sheet

I saved in the PC as in the below code

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Table Export</title>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#dvData').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
<div id="dvData">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column One </th>
        <th>Column Two</th>
        <th>Column Three</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row1 Col1</td>
        <td>row1 Col2</td>
        <td>row1 Col3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>row2 Col1</td>
        <td>row2 Col2</td>
        <td>row2 Col3</td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row3 Col1</td>
        <td>row3 Col2</td>
        <td>row3 Col3</td>  
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br/>
<a href="" id="btnExport">edit</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't work and export the file but other jQuery examples works, what is the problem?

Comment: please put ur code in $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: Did you check the error console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use document ready like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
     window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +encodeURIComponent($('#dvData').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot YogeshWaran its working Thanks again Please can you help me with my question [http://bit.ly/10W0vxg]:)

Comment: @Priya: please don't obfuscate your URLs, you're not charged per-character, and we like to know where we're going.

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry i didn't get it and by the way i am new to stack overflow

Comment: @Priya: what didn't you get?